# Laravel 10 Str::excerpt() with forward slash (/) in phrase throws preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'y'

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel 10 (PHP 8.1.13) application I try to use Laravel's Str::excerpt() with a / in the second argument (phrase):

```php
Str::excerpt('This is m/y name', 'm/y', [
            'radius' => 3
        ]);
```

This results in preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'y' exception thrown in
vendor / laravel / framework / src / Illuminate / Support / Str.php : 343:

```php
preg_match('/^(.*?)('.preg_quote((string) $phrase).')(.*)$/iu', (string) $text, $matches);
```

With every other special char it works just fine. I have already tried to escape the forward slash with a leading backlash, resulting in the same error.

```php
Str::excerpt('This is m/y name', 'm\/y', [
            'radius' => 3
        ]);
```

It's obviously that it has to do with the preg_quote((string) $phrase) inside Laravel's Str::excerpt(). But is there a way to escape the forward slash or do I need use a different excerpt implementation?

Comment: Would you not escape it on the pattern? `'This is m\/y name'`

Comment: Try with combining double quotes and also double backslash escape. Just an idea.

Comment: `Str::excerpt` is in a vendor file and not recommended to change.

Comment: Oddly, this might be something to bring up as a [Laravel bug report](https://github.com/laravel/framework), especially if you need to have the slash in your phrase.

Comment: @KarlHill: It is part of the framework, so it's not a good idea to change it.

Comment: @Tpojka: I tried Str::excerpt("This is m\y name", "m\\/y", [
            'radius' => 3
        ]);
and Str::excerpt("This is m\y name", "m\/y", [
            'radius' => 3
        ]);

Comment: @jhmckimm: Good idea, but doesn't fix it :(

Comment: @Clansi I see, what's happening is that your input is being passed to `preg_quote` which is escaping the backslash... How annoying. I think what's gone wrong here is that someone has assumed `preg_quote` would also escape forward slashes, when in fact it does not. This is definitely a bug then, I would file a report with Laravel.

Answer (score 3):

Just found that it has been fixed in 10.29 (I was using 10.27): https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/48765